# MySql procedure returning variable result from different tables

Tags: mysql

Is it possible within a MySQL stored procedure to return the result of the first select that has a value?

For example, imagine I have 3 tables with identical columns. I want to run a select against each of them in order. If the first has results, then return those results only. If it does not, check the second etc...

So something like this in psuedo code!

```
if (select code from table1 where col='apples') then
    return these results
else (select code from table2 where col='apples') then
    return these results
else (select code from table3 where col='apples') then
    return these results
endif
```

I cannot use a UNION (I don't think) as I want to stop once I get a set of results. So, if I find a match after the first query, just return those results even though subsequent queries might return results too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` function to see whether any records are found and if yes, use the select. Encapsulate this logic within a block so you can leave at any time once a result set is found. You may also use prepared statements

your psuedo code would look like this in MySQL.

```
SearchBlock:Begin
    SET rCount = coalesce((select count(*) from table1 where col='apples'),0);
    IF (rCount > 0) THEN
        select code from table1 where col='apples';
        LEAVE SearchBlock;
    END IF;

    SET rCount = coalesce((select count(*) from table2 where col='apples'),0);
    IF (rCount > 0) THEN
        select code from table2 where col='apples';
        LEAVE SearchBlock;
    END IF;

    SET rCount = coalesce((select count(*) from table2 where col='apples'),0);
    IF (rCount > 0) THEN
        select code from table2 where col='apples';
        LEAVE SearchBlock;
    END IF;
End SearchBlock;
```

Comment: Hi @krish KM, thanks for your reply. That looks like it would work well for what I want. However, could I ask is it very inefficient and should I be looking at doing things completely differently?  What I mean is that it looks like you have to run each query twice. Once to see if it has results and then again to actually run the select. Am I correct? Also, would you mind explaining how I could use prepared statements as you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: @Jablalr no it is not inefficient for your particular needs. Whether you should be doing this differently is up to you. because we don't know your requirements